# Pyspark G1 Garabage Collector

Tags: garbage-collection, pyspark

I had an error with my pyspark, saying GC collector out of memory. 
I read an article about G1 Garbage collector, so I want to try it. 
How do I set it in pyspark application? I couldn't find any instruction on that..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> The main point to remember here is that the cost of garbage collection
>   is proportional to the number of Java objects
>   This is the start...
>   To optimize it by spark [see this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/tuning.html#garbage-collection-tuning) and [see this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#Dynamically-Loading-Spark-Properties) to discover the principal conf paramters to use.

The rest is experience...